# Session Security for User Log-in

Tags: asp.net, security, session, form-authentication

In ASP.NET some developers use Sessions for detect the user is Logineed or not and keep some data in Session Variables.
In the other hand, I read we can use Form Authentication for this operation but i don't know it.
If i using session,is it enough secure for this operations or not?

Thanks in Advanced.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with Forms Authentication. Aside from getting all of the built-in .NET security functions, its also less easily abused (compared to sessions).